# Why can't I set a Double object equal to an int? - Java

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Why do I get an error when attempting to initialize a `Double` to an `int`, even though it does not throw an exception when using the primitive type, `double`?

```
Double a = 1;   // error - incompatible types
Double b = 1.0; // OK
double c = 1;   // OK
```

Why is the behavior different between the class `Double` and the primitive type, `double`?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7

Comment: Java will only do so many conversions in one go.  It will either widen the type OR auto-box but not both in one step.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Although *boxing* optionally followed by *widening* is fine, if later is possible :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you initialize your `Double` as:

```
Double a = 1;
```

There needs to be done 2 things:

- Boxing `int` to `Integer`
- Widening from `Integer` to `Double`

Athough, boxing is fine, but widening from `Integer` to `Double` isn't valid. So, it fails to compile.

Note that, Java doesn't support *Widening* followed by *Boxing* conversion, as specified in [JLS §5.2:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2)

> Assignment contexts allow the use of one of the following:
>
> - an identity conversion (§5.1.1)
> - a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2)
> - a widening reference conversion (§5.1.5)
> - a boxing conversion (§5.1.7) optionally followed by a widening
>     reference conversion
> - an unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) optionally followed by a widening
>     primitive conversion.

Your 2<sup>nd</sup> assignment goes through *boxing conversion*.
While 3<sup>rd</sup> assignment goes through *widening conversion*.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of Java's autoboxing which will convert 1 into an Integer instead of a Double.

```
Double a = Double.valueOf(1);
```

should work

Comment: or just `Double a = 1d;`

Answer (score 0):

The because of auto boxing

```
 Double a = 1;     equals to Double a = Integer.valueOf(1);

 Double b = 1.0;   equals to Double b = Double.valueOf(1);    

 double c = 1;     equals to double c = (double) 1;
```

What more you can do is to mark your number with `D`.

```
 Double d = 1D; equals to Double d = Double.valueOf(1);
```